# Display archive (in dropdown) and category (in dropdown) inside a page

Tags: php, templates, drop-down-menu, archive

I have a question:

I have a Archive Template page and in there i want to display two dropdown menus: archive and category dropdown and when i clicked e.g. Archive for the month of November, so then all items will be displayed from November on the side and it also works ... However, if you select a menu item, then all items will be displayed and not only the post for this category.

Here is the Code:

In archives.php comes this code (and here is all correct... i think):

```
<div id="archive-browser">
    <div>
        <h4>Month</h4>
        <select id="month-choice">
            <option val="no-choice"> &mdash; </option>
            <?php wp_get_archives(array(
                'type'    => 'monthly',
                'format'  => 'option'
            )); ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Category</h4>
        <?php 
            wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none= -- ');?> 
    </div>
</div>
<div id="archive-wrapper">
<div id="archive-pot">
</div></div>
```

And in the other Template, named Archives-getter.php comes this code and here is somewhere the mistake:

```
<?php
    /*
        Template Name: Archives Getter
    */
    $year = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST));
    $month = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST));
    $cat = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST));
    $querystring = "year=$year&monthnum=$month&cat=$cat&posts_per_page=-1";
    query_posts($querystring); 
?>
<?php if (($year == '') && ($month == '') && ($cat == '-1')) { ?>
    <table id="archives-table"><tr><td style='text-align: center; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px;'>Please choose from above.</td></tr></table>
<?php } else { ?>
    <table id="archives-table">
        <?php    
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'PostThumb', true); ?>" alt="" style="width: 35px;" /></td>
                    <td><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php comments_popup_link(' ', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></td>
                    <td><?php the_date('m/j/Y'); ?></td>
                </tr>
        <?php 
            endwhile; else:
                echo "<tr><td style='text-align: center; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px;'>Nothing found.</td></tr>";
            endif; 
        ?>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

This two are connected together, so when I run the archives template, it calls the data from getter.

I think the mistake is somewhere by the querystring... only the category dropdown shows not the posts. Thanks for your help.

---

Thank you, but the archive dropdown works fine... however the category dropdown shows not the post on her category when i click on category XY. Here is the Jquery code, because it is with this and post field names connected:

And the post field names have i changed in:

```
$year = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['year_y']));
    $month = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['month_m']));
    $cat = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['cat_c']));



jQuery(function() {

    jQuery("#archive-wrapper").height(jQuery("#archive-pot").height());

    jQuery("#month-choice").change(function() {

        // Update category choice dynamically

        // This is much harder, needs another intermediary getter

    });

    jQuery("#archive-browser select").change(function() {

        jQuery("#archive-pot")
            .empty()
            .html("<div style='text-align: center; padding: 30px;'><img src='' /></div>");



        var dateArray = jQuery("#month-choice").val().split("/");

        var y = dateArray[3];

        var m = dateArray[4];

        var c = jQuery("#cat").val();



        jQuery.ajax({



            url: "/archive-getter/", 

            dataType: "html",

            type: "POST",

            data: ({

                "year_y": y,

                "month_m" : m,

                "cat_c" : c


            }),

            success: function(data) {

                jQuery("#archive-pot").html(data);



                jQuery("#archive-wrapper").animate({

                    height: jQuery("#archives-table tr").length * 50

                });



            }



        });



    });



});
```

Comment: you should edit your question or add comment . not add it as an answer when it is not an answer. beside I didn't correct the drop down, I corrected the values that goes into posts query, which is the part that shows the posts which you said doesn't work.  I ll edit my answer to contain the new _post names you mentioned here

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the post field name here:

```
$year = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST));
$month = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST));
$cat = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST));
```

should be something like this (names depend on your form fields

```
$year = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['year_y']));
$month = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['month_m']));
$cat = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['cat_c']));
```

This kind of form inputs should have name:

```
<select id="month-choice">
```

like this

```
<select id="month-choice" name="month">
```

Comment: Hello,

Sorry that I clicked on reply ... So I'm now really all possible combinations of here tried "http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts Example_4" , but unfortunately that does not drop down menu still ... it simply will not display the items that those products by category or class of the month XY XY ....

I do not know what to do yet ... has anyone an idea or can someone  test the script. Thank you for your answers.